# Get username with window authentication

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller

We need to implement a code with C# for window authentication with MVC application. Like when user tries to access a URL s/he will get window authentication popup and user will enters his/her user name and password and we need to get the username in C# and store it into database.

I am able to retrieve user name using below code but it is only when hosting app on local host once I host n server I am getting pool identity as user name.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

How can I get even after host application?

Comment: The SystemInformation class in the System.Windows.Forms namespace can give you the current username that is logged in. Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: What kind of application? ASP.NET apps should use `Page.User` or `Controller.User`.

Comment: @LexLi It is a MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you must use a personal access token :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the username in the MVC when you enabled the windows auth, I suggest you could use User.Identity.Name instead of System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.

You could write a test as below:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.PrincipalName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        ViewBag.Name = User.Identity.Name;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<br />
The Principalname is :  @ViewBag.PrincipalName 
<br />
The name is :  @ViewBag.Name
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: User.Identity.Name, for this I am getting guest user name instead of whatever user has typed on window authentication pop up box.

Comment: As far as I know, the User.Identity.Name for the windows authentication is the domain and username. Normally, the client use use domain/username to login in the your application.Could you please tell use what is the guest user name?Could you please share the details webconfig setting? It will be more easily for us to reproduce the issue and find out the solution.